# JMeter hangs during performance testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

1. I am trying to simulate 100 threads request with 4 different users, all the 97 requests were sent and received but the remaining 3 requests still showing as executing.
2. I have to manually stop the Jmeter and then only the remaining request are passed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your machine probably doesn't have the resources to execute the requests or Java isn't configured appropriately.  Take a look at [this article](http://andrewdwyer.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/executing-large-scale-tests-in-apache-jmeter/) and [this one](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips)

Comment: If the machine does not have the resources to execute the requests or if Java isn't configured properly, the OP shouldn't be able to access JMeter GUI after it is hung up. He clearly mentions that he is stopping the test manually and post which JMeter passes the requests.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are running `jmeter` in a window mode, please check for attributes provided for heap memory etc. (those should not exceed more than half of the RAM on the machine you are running upon)

Comment: One cannot use JMeter from the GUI post hang up of the same due to OOME. Besides, why shouldn't the heap memory exceed more than half of the RAM on my machine? I can allocate 12 GB of heap to my application if I have 16 gigs. That shouldn't be a problem. The problem arises in a 32 bit OS when other processes are also running but Oracle does not cap the upper limit of heap to any specific value such as half.