# Why do some threads not close/ stop within my session of JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

Why do some threads not close/ stop within my session of JMeter?

I have a simple https request to a URL, 1500users, 20second ramp up, 5 iteration

For some reason the threads freeze when ramping down, for example 1500users would ramp down but when reach around the 30mark the 30 threads freeze and dont stop, any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: which HTTP implementation are you using? and which version of JMeter?
For example HttpClient3.1 is not very good with timeouts (it's missing timeouts for some situations, so requests may hang if server does not return the answer). Also "InterruptedException" is not handled properly in some cases (seems much better in JMeter 3.1 or higher, but was pretty bad before).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter hangs during performance testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716101/jmeter-hangs-during-performance-testing)

Comment: @kiri thanks for the message, im using 'Sampler'> 'Http Request' > Protocol: 'https' > Implementation: 'HttpClient4'

Comment: Just to clarify: the client itself is not frzen, only the running threads are stuck in that running state, right?
If yes, I still think they are doing something, which does not handle InterruptedException correctly. With HttpClient4 it should happen less, but still possible. What's the longest you waited?Try to apply timeouts as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207879/configuring-response-timeout-in-apache-jmeter

You also have an error in log, which you should check (that red "1" at the top)

Comment: @Kiril S yes they are stuck in running state, I have waited for example 30+mins and still they havent closed, thanks I will look into the link

Answer (score 0):

**Don't ever run your JMeter tests in GUI mode**, use GUI only for tests development and/or debugging. When it comes to load test execution make sure you run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#load_test_running).

Also make sure you are following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article.